# How to mimic Keyboard animation on iOS 7 to add "Done" button to numeric keyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, keyboard

I had been doing something like this to mimic the keyboard animation on older version of iOS.

```
CGRect keyboardBeginFrame;
[[note.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardBeginFrame];
self.doneKeyboardButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, (keyboardBeginFrame.origin.y + keyboardBeginFrame.size.height) - 53, 106, 53);
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject] addSubview:self.doneKeyboardButton];

CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(self.doneKeyboardButton.superview.frame.origin.x + self.doneKeyboardButton.frame.size.width/2,
                                self.doneKeyboardButton.superview.frame.size.height - self.doneKeyboardButton.frame.size.height/2);

[UIView animateWithDuration:[[note.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue]-.02
                      delay:.0
                    options:[[note.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] intValue]
                 animations:^{
                     self.contentView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.contentView.frame, 0, -TextFieldViewMovement);
                     self.doneKeyboardButton.center = newCenter;
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

However, this has stopped working on iOS7. It seems like the values returned are no longer exactly correct, and the Done button no longer exactly mimics the Keyboard display animation.

Comment: I tried the approach as you aselect the answer. But I do not know how you are setting the frame.

Comment: Esspecially self.contentview.frame.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

In iOS 7, the keyboard uses a new, undocumented animation curve. While some have noted that using an undocumented value for the animation option works, I prefer to use the following:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:[notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue]];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:[notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] unsignedIntegerValue]];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

// work

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

While block based animations are the recommendation, the animation curve returned from the keyboard notification is an `UIViewAnimationCurve`, while the option you would need to pass to block based animations is an `UIViewAnimationOptions`. Using the traditional UIView animation methods allows you to pipe the value directly in. **Most importantly, this will use the new undocumented animation curve (integer value of 7) and cause the animation to match the keyboard**. And, it will work just as well on iOS 6 and 7.

Comment: Simple! Robust! Genius! This solution also lets me get rid my `AACViewAnimationOptionsFromCurve` function.

Comment: Just replaced all my keyboard animation blocks with this old style. Feels like a step back, but it works. Looking forward to going back to blocks once Apple realizes its mistake.

Comment: I am reading that you can simply shift the curve value by 16 to get the options value. `options = curve << 16;` But either way it is not working for me.

Comment: @Brennan get the curve with `UIViewAnimationCurve curve = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue]` and use block animation like this `UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:delay options:(curve << 16) animations:` - hope that helps.

Comment: Translating this to Swift is straightforward, except for the curve param which requires this bit of ugly: `var curve:UIViewAnimationCurve = UIViewAnimationCurve(rawValue: info[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey]!.integerValue)!`.

Comment: To those who think this a step backwards: You could always wrap this in a method and make your method take (and execute) a block. Then your frequently repeated code is nice at least.

Answer (score 23):

I had the same issue and managed to get the animation working with the following parameters for iOS 7:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0
         usingSpringWithDamping:500.0f
          initialSpringVelocity:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:animBlock
                     completion:completionBlock];
```

**EDIT:** these values were obtained through debug, and ***can*** change with new iOS versions. [@DavidBeck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19235995/1077288) works for me in iOS 7 also so I'm linking it here.

Comment: I'm marking you as correct because my original solution is not very stable.

Comment: [@DavidBeck's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19235995/242933) is better because it's simple, theoretically perfect, and stable (backward & forward-compatible), whereas the arguments used in this answer might not be exact, and even if they are perfect for iOS 7.0 (as [@Sabobin commented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837166/how-to-mimic-keyboard-animation-on-ios-7-to-add-done-button-to-numeric-keyboar#comment28262150_18876428)), they might be off for other versions of iOS. For example, I'm pretty sure they're off for iOS < 7.0.

Comment: perfect, help me so much +1

Answer (score 10):

Apple is using some undocumented animation with the value 7 in iOS 7.

However the declaration of `UIViewAnimationCurve` defines values for 0 to 3

```
typedef enum {
   UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut, // 0
   UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn,
   UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut,
   UIViewAnimationCurveLinear // 3
} UIViewAnimationCurve;
```

The `UIViewAnimationOptions` you need for block based animations is defined as

```
enum {
   // ...
   UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut            = 0 << 16,
   UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn               = 1 << 16,
   UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut              = 2 << 16,
   UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear               = 3 << 16,

   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone            = 0 << 20,
   // ...
};
```

It seems that Apple reserves 4 bits for the animaton curve (20 - 16 = 4) which allows values from 0 to 15 (so there are probably more undocumented values).

With this knowledge you can simply transform an `UIViewAnimationCurve` into `UIViewAnimationOptions` by shifting it about 16 bits. In your example this means:

```
options:[[note.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] intValue] << 16
```

Comment: I'm sure you mean 4 bits. :)

Comment: And still this approach hard codes an enum's value into your program's logic. Not good from my perspective, very non OO oriented.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `animateWithDuration` block and set curve inside it. It's clean and work well.

```
UIViewAnimationCurve curve = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue];
double duration = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];

[UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                    delay:0
                  options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState 
               animations:^{
                 [UIView setAnimationCurve:curve];
                 /* ANIMATION HERE */
                 // don't forget layoutIfNeeded if you use autolayout
               }
               completion:nil];
```

Happy coding!

**UPDATE**

You can use a simple UIViewController category written by me https://github.com/Just-/UIViewController-KeyboardAnimation

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to add the button inside a toolbar (similarly as the mobile Safari does it), you can just use the property `inputAccessoryView` (both `UITextField` and `UITextView` have it) and save yourself all the trouble. This hidden gem is little known, I am glad that I stumbled upon it.

It works on both iOS 6 and iOS 7, I am using it in my app [Routie](http://www.routieapp.com).

Comment: Not a bad idea, but this question was focused more on how to actually add an overlay button inside the unused button space in the number pad.

Comment: Ah, ok. I thought it was meant that the button will be above the keyboard. Where exactly it is supposed to be added? Lower left corner? I don't know, it seems very unusual. But maybe I could help out, because I am going to create the whole keyboard myself (I need . and - there), and put it on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

This is working just fine for me...  The duration is caught when the keyboard is shown.  I know hardcoding the options means that it could break in the future, but it works for 7 and 8.  That is good enough for us for now...

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:self.animationDuration
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     [self.view layoutIfNeeded]; completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     if (finished)
                     {
                         if (completion)
                             completion();
                     }
                 }];
```

Comment: Actually, after thinking about this for about -3 seconds, I went with Anton's answer.

Answer (score 0):

**iOS 10+**
**Swift 5**

A more modern alternative (iOS 10+ and Swift) is to use `UIViewPropertyAnimator`, which not only accepts `UIView.AnimationCurve` but is a more modern animator.

Most likely you'll be working with `UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey`, which we are to treat as an `NSNumber`. The documentation for this key is (Apple's own notation, not mine):

```
public class let keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey: String // NSNumber of NSUInteger (UIViewAnimationCurve)
```

Using this approach, we can eliminate any guesswork and just plug and play:

```
if let kbDuration = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber,
    let kbTiming = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber, // doc says to treat as NSNumber
    let timing = UIView.AnimationCurve.RawValue(exactly: kbTiming), // takes an NSNumber
    let curve = UIView.AnimationCurve(rawValue: timing) // takes a raw value {
    let duration = kbDuration.doubleValue
    let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: duration, curve: curve) {
        // add animations
    }
    animator.startAnimation()
}
```