# How can I correctly animate a view on top of the keyboard when a UITabBar is present?

Tags: ios7, autolayout, uitabbar, uikeyboard

The technique detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837166/how-to-mimic-keyboard-animation-on-ios-7-to-add-done-button-to-numeric-keyboar) about how to correctly animate a view (like a comment entry box) to stay on top of the keyboard as it animates in and out works well. Set a vertical height constraint between the bottom of your view and the bottom layout guide and animate it to the keyboard frame's height, using the keyboard animation's curve and duration.

But when you are using a `UITabBarController` and have a tab bar at the bottom of the screen this does not work—you end up with a `UITabBar`-height gap between your view and the keyboard, as the bottom layout guide is still at the top of the tab bar, but the keyboard covers the tab bar and its frame's height is calculated from the bottom of the screen.

Simply subtracting the tab bar height from the keyboard frame height doesn't work as this mucks up the animation. You can clearly see this effect in the iPhone Facebook app on iOS 7; there is a gap between the comment box and the keyboard when you dismiss the keyboard:

[image: Note gap between bottom of comment entry box and tab bar as keyboard animates away]

(Try calling and dismissing the keyboard on a post in the iPhone Facebook app to see the animation effect yourself.)

I can think of a couple of ways to fix this and I want to know if anyone has tried these or has any better ideas:

1) Hide the UITabBar in such a way the bottom layout guide ends up at the bottom of the screen (how?) before the keyboard animates away and show it again before the keyboard animates back

2) Adjust the animation curve/timing such that my view "keeps up" with the keyboard correctly (without guessing/hacking it, preferably)

3) Attach the bottom constraint of my view to something other than the bottom layout guide (what?)

Answer (score 1):

I have been puzzling on this and I found a solution, it may not be too elegant, but ok

In the method where you end editing and thus start hiding the keyboard, you can start a `NSTimer` with `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05` that calls a method like this:

#### Set before calling the `NSTimer`:

```
// define these once
textViewHeight = self.textView.frame.size.height;
tabBarHeight = self.tabBar.frame.size.height;
maxOrigin = self.view.frame.size.height - textViewHeight - tabBarHeight;
```

#### Called by the `NSTimer`:

```
CGFloat currentOrigin = self.textView.frame.origin.y;

if (currentOrigin > maxOrigin)
{
    CGRect f = self.textView.frame;
    f.origin.y = maxOrigin;
    [self.textView setFrame:f];

    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
}
```

This way the animation continues to set it to where it already is and the view stays with the keyboard until it reaches the `maxOrigin' on the y-axis