# View aligned to top of keyboard appears in wrong place in iOS 9 Shortcut Bar only mode

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard, ios9

iOS 9 adds a [Shortcut Bar](https://www.apple.com/ios/ios9-preview/) to the iOS 8 [QuickType bar](http://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/quicktype/).

As part of this change, if you connect a bluetooth keyboard to an iPad, the keyboard is in a minimized Shortcut Bar only mode (which can be simulated by pressing command-k in the simulator).

I have code which gets the keyboard height using a method similar to the following:

```
CGRect keyboardFrame = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
CGFloat keyboardHeight = keyboardFrame.size.height; // = 313
```

The problem is that when the keyboard is toggled between the expanded and collapsed state, the height remains the same, causing my view to appear in its old location:

Desired behavior:

> [image]
>   (Notice how the red view is attached to the top of the keyboard)

Actual behavior:

> [image]

What's the correct way to get the red view to be attached to the top of the keyboard?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that most code out there ([including](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html) Apple's) ignores the fact that *UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey* is a *CGRect* and not a *CGSize*.

```
// ❌ Bad code, do not use
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    CGRect bkgndRect = activeField.superview.frame;
    bkgndRect.size.height += kbSize.height;
    [activeField.superview setFrame:bkgndRect];
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, activeField.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height) animated:YES];
}
```

Here you see that only the keyboard height (`kbSize.height`) is being used. The origin of the rect is important, and should not be ignored.

When the keyboard is visible, this is the rect that is reported:

> [image]

When the keyboard is in Shortcut Bar only mode, this is the rect:

> [image]

Notice how the majority of the keyboard is offscreen, yet it is still the same height.

To get the correct behavior, use [CGRectIntersection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectIntersection) with the view's bounds and the keyboard frame within that view:

```
// ✅ Good code, use
CGRect keyboardScreenEndFrame = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
CGRect keyboardViewEndFrame = [self.view convertRect:keyboardScreenEndFrame fromView:self.view.window];
CGRect keyboardFrame = CGRectIntersection(self.view.bounds, keyboardViewEndFrame);
CGFloat keyboardHeight = keyboardFrame.size.height; // = 55
```

For this same reason, `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` should be used as opposed to `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey`.